How to say "discipline" in the sense of "the discipline of a circuit design engineer"?
请问，这句中的discipline翻译为汉语怎么说

We collaborated in writing this book with the specific
intention of combining the discipline of a circuit design
engineer with the perspective of a practicing experimental physicist and teacher of electronics. Thus, the treatment in this book reflects our philosophy that electronics, as currently practiced, is basically a simple art, a combination of some basic laws, rules of thumb, and a large bag of tricks. For these reasons we have omitted entirely the usual discussions of solid-state physics, the h-parameter model of transistors, and complicated network theory, and reduced to a bare minimum the mention of load lines and the s-plane. The treatment is largely nonmathematical, with strong encouragement of circuit brainstorming and mental (or, at most, back-of-the-envelope) calculation of circuit values and performance.

The above paragraph is from the fourth paragraph of the preface of the first edition of "The Art of Electronics," third edition. Here is download link of the book: https://gofile.io/d/mwVeUx
Thank you.

"Discipline" here primarily suggests the professional and/or industrial experience of the circuit design engineer, but the word is also used to contrast with the words "practicing experimental physicist and teacher" to avoid repetition. The sentence could equally have been written practicing industrial circuit design engineer with the perspective and discipline of an experimental physicist. But I digress...these are not appropriate questions for Chinese SE, you should ask them at one of the English language StackExchanges.

@dROOOze As for "these are not appropriate questions for Chinese SE, you should ask them at one of the English language StackExchanges."，我不太理解，这个问题为什么不适合Chinese SE，请问你能详细说下原因吗？

Translation questions on Chinese SE are for "I want to say ABC in Chinese, my attempt is XYZ, does this sound natural or is there a better way to say it?". Your question is "I don't quite know what precisely this means, can you help me write it in my native language?" (which just happens to be Chinese, but it could be any other language). This is why it's more appropriate to ask at an English StackExchange - after they help you figure out what exactly it means, you should be able to say it in your native language (Chinese, or some other language).

@dROOOze Thank for your explain.

我们经常看到，人们在翻译英文的文章时，翻译出来的中文语句好像不够通顺。尤其是遇到包含复杂的定语从句，分词短语，和介词短语的时候，翻译出来的中文语句常常带有一种“洋腔洋调”的感觉。这是因为中国人讲话作文的习惯和英美的人们有很大的不同。按照中文的习惯，人们一般使用简短的语句，而不太喜欢在一个主句中再套用其他的子句。还有一个原因是，英文的词汇往往含有多重的意思，翻译成中文的时候，如果“照本宣科”的套用，就会“词不达意”，甚至引起歧义和误解。这就需要结合对文章上下文的理解，原文作者的意图，甚至英文读者的解读方式，选择比较适合中文读者理解的词汇和语气。
For example:
We collaborated in writing this book with the specific intention of combining the discipline of a circuit design engineer with the perspective of a practicing experimental physicist and teacher of electronics.
Analyzing this long sentence, we found that it includes 3 parts: 1 main sentence and 2 sub-sentences.
(1) We collaborated in writing this book.
(2) (We have the) specific intention of something.
(3) (We) combined A with B.
The difficult words are: (thanks to @r13)
A: the discipline of a circuit design engineer.
B: the perspective of a practicing experimental physicist and teacher of electronics.
我们用中文说这三句话，就是
(1) 我们(几位)作者合作完成了这本(教科)书。
(2) 在本书中，我们特别注意到(这件事情)。
(3) 要把两方面的(知识,实践经验,理论,见解)结合起来。
直接理解discipline和perspective这两个词汇，可能比较困难。我们可以从人物的角色来看。design engineer 是设计工程师，physicist and teacher 是物理学家和教师。设计工程师是工业生产方面的，具有电路设计的实际经验。物理学家和教师是从事理论研究和教学的，对电路理论和科学实验有比较完整和系统的知识。所以，discipline 翻译成"实际经验", perspective 翻译成"理论知识"
我的中文翻译如下：
我们几位作者合作完成了这本教科书。在本书中，我们希望把实践和理论两方面的知识结合起来。此书既包含了电路设计工程师的实践经验, 也包含了实验物理学方面的科学家和教授的理论知识。

非常感谢你的答案，好专业的分析，首先给出你对翻译的见解，其次是英文句子的分析，然后给出你的理解，最后给出你的翻译，这个答案非常值得我学习。你的理解，答案和这本书 https://gofile.io/d/5uiC4P  的第一版前言的第一段相照应"We have attempted to combine the pragmatic approach of the practicing physicist with the quantitative approach of the engineer, who wants a thoroughly evaluated circuit design."。我感觉你在中文和英文方面都有很深的研究，之前看过你在这个网站的其他答案，基本上都有独到很深的见解，答案的质量都很高。再次感谢你。

專業 - special field of study; specialized subject; specialized trade or profession
專業訓練 - special field of training; specialize training
We collaborated in writing this book with the specific
intention of combining "the discipline of a circuit design
engineer" with "the perspective of a practicing experimental physicist and teacher of electronics".

我們合作寫這本書的具体的意图是結合"电路设计工程师的專業訓練/知識"和"实际从事实验物理学家以及电子学老師的觀點/見解".


Thank you for answer. Here is download link https://gofile.io/d/5uiC4P for third version of the Art of Electronics, please see again the first four paragraphs of preface to the first edition , then give your view.  Thank you very much.

Thank you for your edited answer.

Circuit design is a very delicate business. In a modern CPU, the transistors are measured in a few nanometres. At these sizes, even if the CPU works on just 3.3V, that voltage can jump across a gap of nanometre size and leak. The business of designing circuitry is therefore arduous and very challenging. Thus the person tasked with this job must be rigorous in the extreme. He, or she, must have a lot of self-discipline.
The word discipline comes to us from Latin: discipulus "pupil, student, follower"
discipline originally meant:

"penitential chastisement; punishment for the sake of correction,"

(Spare the rod and spoil the child!
省了棍棒，坏了孩子。
A practice which lasted thousands of years and was only outlawed in British State Schools in 1987, in 1998 in private schools.)
Later, discipline came to mean:

"branch of instruction or education"

Now we have this ambiguous sentence:

We collaborated in writing this book with the specific intention of
combining the  discipline of a circuit design engineer with the
perspective of a practicing experimental physicist and teacher of
electronics.

Does discipline here mean:

self-discipline (absolute attention to detail)?

Or does it mean:

"branch of instruction or education"?

We cannot know from this sentence alone. Therefore, you will have trouble translating this sentence correctly.
Either we have:
We collaborated in writing this book with the specific intention of combining the  discipline (field of research) of a circuit design engineer with the perspective of a practising experimental physicist and teacher of electronics.
我们合作编写这本书，其具体目的是将电路设计工程师的研究领域与实践实验物理学家和电子教师的观点相结合。
Or:
We collaborated in writing this book with the specific intention of combining the  absolute attention to detail (self-discipline) of a circuit design engineer with the perspective of a practicing experimental physicist and teacher of electronics.
我们合作编写这本书，其具体目的是将电路设计工程师对细节的绝对关注与实践实验物理学家和电子教师的视角相结合。
More context would, most likely, clarify the meaning here of discipline.

That's a great analysis! Thank you for your insights. I've revised my question to include more relevant details.

Realistically, there's only two plausible interpretations of the word "discipline" in this context: (a) "discipline" in the sense of "the discipline of a soldier", which would translate to 纪律 (or some synonym), or (b) "discipline" in the sense of "academic discipline", which would translate to 学科 (or some synonym).
Judging from the English side of things, it's a bit ambiguous, but I'd lean towards 学科, because the tone of the text makes me feel it's fairly relaxed, and "discipline" in the sense of "the discipline of a soldier" does not seem to match that tone.
However, I managed to track down a related phrase from the Chinese translation of the second edition 《电子学》:



This version uses the phrase 规范要求.

Thank you for answer, but I want to say 学科 is not accurate or appropriate in here。Here is download link for third version Art of Electronics  https://gofile.io/d/5uiC4P . It seems that your native language is English, so please see again the first four paragraphs of preface to the first second  then give your view.  英文版翻译为中文版的技术书籍好多错误的，有的甚至语句不通，例如你给的那个有中文翻译的链接中，关于“每一个电子专业都有很好的治疗方法”，我想知道你对于这句话有什么看法？Thank you very much.

另外你的答案中有提到as currently practiced，你给的那个有中文翻译的链接中，对应的翻译应该是就目前的实践而言，我非常想知道，你对这句英文翻译为中文的就目前的实践而言有什么看法？

Correct: "so please see again the first four paragraphs of preface to the first second then give your view."  should be "so please see again the first four paragraphs of preface to the first edition then give your view."

It is not cool nor relevant to dig up my 2-year-old exam results to try to discredit me.  I'm simply quoting a Chinese translation of this passage (which I believe is from the Chinese version of this book), and showing you they translated "discipline" to 学科.

还是和你说中文吧。我怕引起不必要的误会，我没有抹黑你的意思，我也没有一点恶意。关于你第2次中文考试分数比第一次少了一点，根本原因是你还没有真正掌握普通话或者汉语。我是没有资格抹黑你的，或许你对我的话有误解，我的英文表达能力不强，我写的英语句子好多语法错误，有的英语句子我也读不明白，我也是一位学习者，我想掌握英语，你想掌握汉语，我们都是语言学习者，应该相互帮助，不应该相互把对方置于对立面。套用曹植(三国时期曹操的弟弟)的话说就是："本是同根生，相煎何太急"。另外你给的翻译链接中”每一个电子专业都有很好的治疗方法“，这句话有问题，我只是想提醒你一下，如果你感觉这句话没问题，我只能说你的中文还需要提高。治疗方法中的治疗是有问题的，治疗一般是说治疗病人的，这句话里面或者整个第一版前言和医院，病人都没有关系，这句话的翻译是错误的。另外关于就目前的实践而言，我把它理解为"作为目前的专家"，我发现这点我是理解错误了。

请记得我们是在进行友好交流的，一切的抹黑与诋毁都是没有必要的。还有就是关于引用内容的问题，我看你相关的自我介绍，应该是个说英语的人，我对西方文明的印象是严谨，不管是说话还是写文章，英语世界中着重强调客观事实，表达一种东西，很少有说类似"根据我的观点"，通过会说根据某个事实，得出某个结论，这点非常值得中国人学习。但是我不清楚的是，如果引用其他东西的话有没有要求，比如说要求引用的内容确保是正确的。你修改后的答案中有引用的部分，非常感谢你提供了一个其他的引用参考，但是我发现你引用的这一部分中包含了”这种治疗方法在很大程度上是非数学的“这个错误，这个错误对于母语是中文的人来说很明显，应该说这种处理方法在很大程度上是非数学的，所以秉持着怀疑的态度，我对你引用的这个内容的可靠度和准确度表示怀疑。另外关于as currently practiced，这个答案解释了practiced的意思，见https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/358791/does-practiced-should-be-consider-as-expert 这个答案的意思好像说practiced不是作为实践的意思，更倾向于habit/custom习惯；风俗，虽然实践在这里感觉也能解释的通，但作为翻译的话不准确，导致英文版作者要表达的意思和中文版的不一样。

明白了，我误以为拷贝的内容是翻译写的，但是我用百度翻译把英文原文翻译成中文后，得到的就是和拷贝的内容相同。那么，很可能我拷贝的内容不准确。

你几分钟之前编辑更新的答案中提到，把discipline解释为规范要求，这个解释还比较合乎情理，句子也通顺，但是你之前把discipline解释为学科，你又没有感觉出不对劲的地方，没有感觉到哪里怪怪的，我只能说你还没有掌握普通话或者汉语的精髓，如果你掌握了普通话或者汉语的精髓，你的汉语考试在满分300分的情况下应该可以得270分或280分。反正我总感觉把discipline解释为学科，句子是怪怪的，句子也不通顺。

你拷贝的内容是个人写的(可以说是个人博客)，出现这种治疗方法在很大程度上是非数学的这样低级的错误，很大程度上，那个中文翻译是机器翻译的结果，另外百度翻译也是比较垃圾的，最垃圾的中文翻译应该是Google的中文翻译了。等你中文学到一定程度了，你是不需要用百度翻译把英文原文翻译成中文，然后来回比较的。我看你在学<猫城记>，我搜了下猫城记，是1932年写的，那个时候中国大概在1920搞白话文运动，我看你视频<猫城记>这本书里面的内容有些还是和现在的说法或表达，有差异，我是不推荐你学<猫城记>。我非常推荐你学现在中国小学的语文教材，这个语文教材和现在的表达是一致的，等你学完小学的语文教材，语文阅读应该没问题了，练习听力的话可以听听bilibili上的视频，不是某个专业课相关的视频(专业课相关的视频你听起来可能比较吃力)，是那种个人拍的视频，然后听力练的差不多了，可以去听中国官方媒体的新闻连播(他们的宣传可以不用理会，他们只宣传中国的好，你要记得你是练习中文听力的，不是让他们给你洗脑的)，试试能不能听懂，听一阵子，听的不明白的话可以再学学中国初中的教材，看完初中的教材，语文的阅读应该就没问题了，然后再去听中国官方媒体的新闻连播，能听明白的话再去参加中文的考试，不然别去参加中文的考试，当然这些只是建议。

你好，这个问题中 @PdotWang 的答案可以作为你学习中文一个很好的范例，这个答案写的很有水平，非常推荐，我作为一个母语为中文的人都很佩服。

I would say 學術 (discipline)
The noun 'discipline; here refers to 'knowledge and skill acquired from long-term study and practice' and that is what we call 學術 (academic)

感谢你的答案，但是the discipline of a circuit design engineer翻译为中文：电路设计工程师的学术感觉句子不太通顺，中文里面好像没有这样的说法
